# Given the following series... the nth term of the series equals to (n - 1)th ^2 +1 and the first term of the series is 1 use recursion

Tags: c, recursion

Given the following series: 1, 2,5,26,677,
..... such that the nth term of the series equals to 
(n-1)th ^2 +1 and the first term of the series is 1. 
Write a program using recursive function named f to compute the nth term. Use for loop to print the 
values of f
irst n terms in the series. You will take input n from the user.

Can anyone help me figure out what the hell I'm doing here? I am not sure how to do this with recursion, I know how to do it without.

Thanks,
t

EDIT: I've got it to do the sequence now, **I just don't know how to fix it where there is a for loop that does the first 5 of this sequence and then the recursion function does the rest:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double n);

int main(){
/*
    Problem 6:
    - Recursive function to generate nth term of f(x)
*/

double nth;
int i = 0,flag=1;
double result;
int seq[] = {1,2,5,26,677};

printf("Please enter the number of terms you would like to generate: 

\n");

    while(flag == 1){
        if(scanf("%lf",&nth) == 1){
            flag = 0;
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid number, program is exiting...\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    result = f(nth);

    return 0;
}


double f(double n){
    // base condition
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        printf("(%.0lf)",pow(f(n-1),2.0) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Start with what you've tried.

Comment: The rule is written in the recursive way. It is like to copy and paste it right into your function.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement it? I'm not sure I understand what recursion looks like.. @EugeneSh.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tidwellxyz: In pseudocode, in would look something like `f(n): if n == 1 then return 1 else return f(n-1)^2 + 1`

Comment: @JohnBode this is the most helpful thing I've recieved on this post.. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnBode I added an edit that shows how I implemented your pseudo code, How do I use a for loop to do the first 5 terms?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t f(size_t nth) {
  return nth == 1 ? 1 : f(nth - 1) * f(nth - 1) + 1;
}

int main() {
  printf("%zu", f(5));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just edited it with the solution I found, but I can't get the for loop for the first 5 numbers.. Any idea?